# Problem adding image overlay (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, overlay

What I want to do is find all images with a particular class name, and place an overlay image over them. My script thus far in jQuery 1.2.6:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  var module = $(".module-contactus div div div");
  module.find("img.let").each( function() {
    var iWidth = $(this).width();
    var iHeight = $(this).height();
    var letimg = $('<img src="/LET.png" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -' + Math.ceil(iHeight/2) + 'px; margin-left: -' + Math.ceil(iWidth/2) + 'px;" />');
    var wrapper = $( '<span style="position: relative; display: inline-block;"></span>' );
    $(this).wrap( wrapper );
    letimg.appendTo( wrapper );
  });
});
```

The `letimg` is not added to the document (according to Firebug). The `span` element successfully wraps the original image though. Also, it does kinda work if I pass `$(this)` into the `appendTo` function, but then it's added inside the original image!

**EDIT:** markup is below. (The extra divs are a consequence of Joomla.)

```
<div class="module-contactus">
<div><div><div>

<img src="/contact1.jpg" />
<img class="let" src="/contact2.jpg" />

</div></div></div>
</div>
```

After the script is run the second image is replaced with:

```
<span style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
<img class="let" src="/contact2.jpg" />
</span>
```

However, it should end up like this:

```
<span style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
<img class="let" src="/contact2.jpg" />
<img src="/LET.png" style="..." />
</span>
```

Comment: to see what's happening we'll need to see the markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
    $("img.let", $(".module-contactus div div div")).each(function() {
        var iWidth = $(this).width();
        var iHeight = $(this).height();
        var letimg = '<img src="http://www.roomsinworcester.co.uk/images/stories/LET.png" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -' + Math.ceil(iHeight/2) + 'px; margin-left: -' + Math.ceil(iWidth/2) + 'px;" />';
        var wrapper = $('<span style="position: relative; display: inline-block;"></span>');
        $(this).wrap(wrapper).after(letimg);
    });
});
```

As a side note.  I took out a couple of your variables, and would say that you could probably continue to remove others (put the img tag directly into the after, the wrapper directly into the wrap function, etc.).  Not a huge deal either way though.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I should have spotted that since I had the image in $(this) I could simply add the overlay after it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need the wrapper at all.

Try something like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var module = $(".module-contactus div div div");
    module.find("img.let").each( function() {                
        var iWidth = $(this).width();                
        var iHeight = $(this).height();                
        var letimg = $('<img src="http://www.roomsinworcester.co.uk/images/stories/LET.png" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -' + Math.ceil(iHeight/2) + 'px; margin-left: -' + Math.ceil(iWidth/2) + 'px;" />');                
        $(this).before(letimg);         
        alert(module.html());
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yes I do need the wrapper because otherwise the overlay cannot be positioned correctly over the image.